# TradingView pine script, did I find a bug in request.security()?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

**EDIT**: This was the first time I "published" a script.  I just got notified that this violated the TOS and the script is no longer accessible.

Here is my script:

```
//@version=5 
indicator("Why Different")

factor = 3
atrPeriod = 10

// built in plot

atr = ta.rma(ta.tr,atrPeriod)
plot(atr, "ATR", color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)

//calculated plot

[s_tr] = request.security(symbol = "SPY", timeframe = timeframe.period, expression = [ta.tr])
s_atr = ta.rma(s_tr, atrPeriod)
plot(s_atr, "ATR", color = color.purple, style=plot.style_line)
```

**EDIT 2**:  I was having no luck trying to get my CALCULATIONS to work so I thought I would simply plot the high/low data.  Guess what?  They are different!!!  Why?  It is supposedly the same data.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Why Different")

plot(high, "hi", color = color.blue, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(low, "lo", color = color.blue, style=plot.style_linebr)

[s_hi,s_lo] = request.security(symbol = "SPY", timeframe = timeframe.period, expression = [high, low])
plot(s_hi, "hi", color = color.purple, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(s_lo, "lo", color = color.purple, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *expression* you can use a variable like `ta.rma(ta.tr,atrPeriod)`

Something like that:

```
s_atr = request.security(symbol = "SPY", timeframe = timeframe.period, expression = ta.rma(ta.tr,atrPeriod))
plot(s_atr, "ATR", color = color.purple, style=plot.style_line)
```

Comment: Awesome! I will try this out when I have time after work. (Posted question during a late lunch).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It did not work. Check out my latest edit. Baffling. It seems like the data used to plot the active chart is pulled from a different source than the data that is pulled by request.security.

Comment: Extended session --> https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Sessions.html#using-sessions-with-request-security

In addition pls consider 'time_tradingday'

Comment: I see it fine. (https://www.tradingview.com/x/2yrQE5bE/)

Comment: Try whit full form of the ticker ID. "AMEX:SPY"

Comment: See my answer below.  Gu5tavo lead me down the correct path but I needed a little support from TV folks

Answer (score 0):

Opened a ticket with TradingView.  @Gu5tavo71, you were almost right.  Upvoted your answer because your comment to your own answer led me to the correct solution.  If you tweak your answer to mention the solution I mention here, I will "accept" it.

The "native" chart uses BATS:SPY.  When I change request.security() to use BATS:SPY it is now 100% in sync.  That is non-intuitive to me.  One would think that request.security() would DEFAULT to the same data source as the charts but allow one to choose a different source if needed.